# Stop onClick functions executing on mount without using () => function(someVal)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting really annoyed by this behaviour that occurs onClick:

If I have:

```
<button onClick={ this.myFunc(myVal) }></button>
```

This fires as soon as component mounts not when button is clicked, hence I need to do the following in order to fix it:

```
<button onClick={ () => this.myFunc(myVal) }></button>
```

But I believe this is not the correct way to achieve this? Also what if I want to actually pass `this.myFunc(myVal)` down to another component? It would not work.

Comment: To `onClick` you have to pass reference to function not call it. Second example is right example, because you pass reference to function. Instead of arrow function you can use `.bind` like so `onClick={ this.myFunc.bind(this, myVal) }`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts just popped it in as a placeholder for function parameter, assume its a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `onClick` attribute expects a *function* as a parameter.
That is why the second setup IS correct, and 1st one is not (unless myFunc returns a function)..

The following are functions:

```
(event) => myFunc(myVal, event)        // anonymous function, which calls myFunc IF executed
myFunc.bind(this, myVal)   // myFunc without parentheses, with parameters - including event - bound
```

The following is not a function

```
myFunc(myVal)              // == THE RESULT of the function, so == whatever myFunc returns
```

In an example:

```
// myFunc is a function that calls another function
// returns length of whatever is passed in
myFunc(val) {
  otherFunc()
  return (val.length)
}
// here: myFunc is defined, but it has never executed: otherFunc was not called

let myVal = [1,2]

let callback = () => myFunc(myVal)
// here myFunc is still NOT called, neither is otherFunc
// callback is now defined as a (anonymous) function, which, whenever called
// will execute the function myFunc, by passing in the value of myVal

let a = myFunc(myVal)
// here: myFunc WILL be called, so also otherFunc
// at this point a == 2 (the length of the array myVal)

let b = callback()
// here, callback function is executed, and so also myFunc
// at this point b == 2
```

Comment: `() => myFunc(myVal)` and `myFunc.bind(this, myVal)` are NOT the same. If `event` needs to be used, only the `.bind()` variation will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Did not know. Will update answer.

Comment: Consider the signature `function myFunc(val, event) { ... }` to understand why that is the case.

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```
<button onClick={ this.myFunc(myVal) }></button>
```

You are telling React that you want the returned value from executing `this.myFunc(myVal)` to be assigned to the `onClick` handler. Instead you, probably want to give it the function with the parameter set as default:

```
<button onClick={ this.myFunc.bind(this, myVal) }></button>
```

This binds `myVal` as the first argument to `this.myFunc` and ensures that the context is also bound properly as well. Keep in mind that this causes the `event` parameter to be passed in as the second parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the function while doing like below, thats why your method gets called immediately after mounting

```
<button onClick={ this.myFunc(myVal) }></button>
```

you have to just assign the function like below

```
<button onClick={ this.myFunc }></button>
```

if you want to pass variables to that method, add that variable to state and access that from ther.

Comment: @ctrlplusb if you read carefully, you do not. @sundar is suggesting to place `myVal` in state, so as to avoid the anti-pattern of default parameters in event callbacks.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts yes.if myVal changes the component view, you can have that inside state.